# alternatedocroot not working on GlassFish 4.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, glassfish, application-server

Here is my `glassfish-web.xml`

```
<glassfish-web-app>
    <property description="Uploaded Images" name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=C:\Uploads" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I have a photo `fff.jpg` in `C:\uploads\`

When i go to `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/uploads/fff.jpg` I get an `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found` error.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you specified the folder name you want to map to in the `dir` attribute.

```
value="from=/uploads/* dir=C:\Uploads"
```

This means that you want to access a folder named "uploads" in the path `C:\Uploads`.

So actually when you access `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/uploads/fff.jpg` it tries to read from `C:\Uploads\uploads\fff.jpg`.

**Solutions:**

Change your `glassfish-web.xml`:

```
value="from=/uploads/* dir=C:\"
```

or create a new folder named "uploads" in `C:\Uploads` and put the pictures in that folder, so that they are really like `C:\Uploads\uploads\fff.jpg`.

**See also:**

- [How to serve static web pages from a JSF application using Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708379/how-to-serve-static-web-pages-from-a-jsf-application-using-glassfish)
- [Alternate docroot not working on glassfish 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617517/alternate-docroot-not-working-on-glassfish-4)
- [alternatedocroot glassfish 3.1.2 maven enterprise project using JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057253/alternatedocroot-glassfish-3-1-2-maven-enterprise-project-using-jsf)